# getting error for if/else in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am relatively very new to SQL queries but I have this stored procedure where I am trying to get value of a declared variable as mentioned below but getting error,

First line is 20 here,

```
declare @m_ID_v int
set @m_ID_v = ( select ID_C from M_T where MName_C = @MName_parameter)

declare @g bit
if (select G_L_Column from G_L_table Where M_ID_Column = @M_ID_variable)
    set @g_v = 1
else
    set @g_variable = 0
```

Exception I get:

> *Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetID, Line 20
>
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'set'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1,
>   Procedure GetID, Line 21 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.*

Now if I remove `declare @g...` and try to parse it, no error occurs

**EDIT**

I want my code to check for returned value by my select statement so "if exists" is not really what am looking for, sorry.

Comment: You've defined a variable called `@g` but the assignment goes to a variable called `@g_v` or `@g_variable` .....

Comment: sorry I changed there names because of company code privacy, sorry, but thanks for correcting me as well :)

Comment: When you say you want to check the returned value, what do you want to check it against?  Do you mean `IF ((SELECT x FROM y WHERE z = @v) = @testVariable)`?  At present you get back `G_L_Column`, but you don't say what you want to check it against.  Also, is `M_ID_Column` unique, allowing you to guarantee that your query only ever returns one row?

Comment: yup it is unique I am a c# programmer and my SQL statement was returning true or false so I thought SQL will check result itself but not really however now its working, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @m_ID_v int
set @m_ID_v = ( select ID_C from M_T where MName_C = @MName_parameter)

declare @g bit
if ((select G_L_Column from G_L_table Where M_ID_Column = @M_ID_variable) = value )
    set @g_v = 1
else
    set @g_variable = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

try use if [exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
declare @g_v bit
if exists(select G_L_Column from G_L_table Where M_ID_Column = @M_ID_variable)
   set @g_v = 1
else
   set @g_v = 0
```

Comment: it did worked and I will accept your answer in 8 minutes but can you also give a bit explanation as well please and if what am doing is best practice or not :)

Comment: @Ignacio, It's the common way to check the query return one or more result. For another case, you may put it as sub query or joining table for avoid if statement and exists keyword.

Comment: sorry I am not looking for "if exists" as it won't gonna work with my logic

Answer (score 1):

You can't say

```
 if (select ...
```

You have to compare something with something else in a `if` statement, or use a boolean function such as `exists`

Comment: cheers, I would give you +1 if I had enough reputation, thanks anyway