# difference between if and if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this stored procedure, I was wondering if "if exists" will actually compare the value returned by select statement or it will just check if that condition can be executed or not, sorry for such a stupid question but I am new to SQL,

```
declare @m_ID_v int
set @m_ID_v = ( select ID_C from M_T where MName_C = @MName_parameter)

declare @g bit
if exists (select G_L_Column from G_L_table Where M_ID_Column = @M_ID_variable)
    set @g_v = 1
else
    set @g_variable = 0
```

my select statement

```
select G_L_Column from G_L_table Where M_ID_Column = @M_ID_variable
```

Is returning either true or false, so just wanna make sure if "if exists" will work as "if"

Comment: The block in `if exists` will execute if your select query inside it return at least 1 record, equal to `if((select query).records.count > 0)`

Comment: how can I use if statement then as it gives me error and I asked a question and they asked me to use  "exists" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892194/getting-error-for-if-else-in-a-stored-procedure

Comment: @Ignacio - Saw you removed the other question. Just for what it's worth, I did not down-vote your question(s).

Comment: @user569711 I was getting negative votes without explanation so I had to remove it, but thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `if exists` is not working as `if`. It doesn't check if the returned value is true or false, it checks if there exists a value.

If your query always returns a value, the `if exists` will always evaluate to true.

Comment: @Ignacio: If the select returns a bit, can't you simpy assign it to the variable?

Comment: I can actually but for the moment I just checking it against a value which solved the problem, ta

Answer (score 2):

[EXISTS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)

Specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows.

**Returns TRUE if a subquery contains any rows.**